# Cannot access env variables react / supabase

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, supabase

I'm creating a react app and Supabase.

when I put the supabaseURL inside the `database.js` file, he reads it but because of the fact that I also have to secure my private api key, he will mention:

> SupabaseClient.ts:87 Uncaught Error: supabaseKey is required.

Somehow, he doesn't read the `.env` or `.env.local` file. check my code here below:

Database.js:

```
 import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js 

 const supabaseUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_SUPABASE_URL;
 const supabaseKey = process.env.REACT_APP_SUPABASE_KEY;

 export const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey)`
```

My env variables :

```
 REACT_APP_SUPABASE_URL="myurl"
 REACT_APP_SUPABASE_KEY="mykey"
```

I have tried both `.env` and `env.local`

Answer (score 0):

I can't pinpoint what the problem is, but below are some things you can look into, and a workaround

### Is the .env file in the correct directory?

the .env file should be inside the root directory of the project

### Workaround, using the dotenv package

the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package helps you read properties from the .env file, you can do

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config()
```

Then you can use the .env variables with `process.env.{variable name}`

Comment: https://github.com/RobertLigthart99/auth-test2 still not working, not clue what i'm doing wrong..

Answer (score 0):

In your case if you re using React and want to access the .env.local, React have his own "dotenv" module, you don't need to import it, when you put in the .env.local file dont't forget to remove the string quote "" like this:

in your .env.local file

```
REACT_APP_SUPABASE_URL=myurl 
REACT_APP_SUPABASE_KEY=mykey
```

than use it like this for your connection

```
process.env.REACT_APP_SUPABASE_URL
process.env.REACT_APP_SUPABASE_KEY
```

once is done you need to restart your React app.

Comment: https://github.com/RobertLigthart99/auth-test2 still not working, not clue what i'm doing wrong..

Comment: hmm your repo is empty, are you sure you have wrote in the .env file without space and string quote ?